# if and if-else statements doesn't work with c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, text-based

so my friend and I are trying to make a text-based video game and I have been doing some research on how to get the programming down. Here is our c++ program so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

char Choice;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    printf("You wake up to darkness.\n");
    printf("Confused and tired, you walk to the nearest house.\n");
    printf("You notice it's abandoned. What do you do?\n");
    printf("1. Walk Away.\n");
    printf("2. Jump.\n");
    printf("3. Open Door.\n");
    printf("Choose wisely.\n");
    cin >> Choice;

    if(Choice=1)
    {
        printf("The House seems to have a gravital pull on you. How strange.\n");
    }

    else if(Choice=2)
    {
        printf("Having Fun?\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when I build and run it will display everything but all answers will be the if(Choice=1) answer. Is there something missing from my program that is needed or do parts contradict each other?

Comment: char: '1' not equal to 1

Comment: Style note:  You probably do not want to mix `printf` with `cin`/`cout`.  It'll mostly work, but they can interact in strange ways, largely because they do not coordinate with each other.  It's not the issue you're having currently.  Rather, if you're learning C++, it's best to get off on the right foot.  Good luck, and happy programming!

Answer (score 7):

You want the comparison operator `==`, not the assignment operator `=`. These are distinct operators. Using `=` will change the value of `Choice`, which is not what you want. (Your compiler should warn you about the use of `=` in an `if` statement.)

`1` is the integer 1. You want to check against the character `'1'` (ASCII value 49), which is different. Use `'1'` instead of `1`.

```
if (Choice == '1')
{
    printf("The House seems to have a gravital pull on you. How strange.\n");
}
else if (Choice == '2')
{
    printf("Having Fun?\n");
}
```

Also, you're mixing two types of I/O. Using `cin` for input is good. You should use its counterpart `cout` for output, rather than `printf`.

```
cout << "You wake up to darkness." << endl;
cout << "Confused and tired, you walk to the nearest house." << endl;
```